# How can I use Facebook JAVA API in my application?

Tags: java, facebook

I have downloaded facebook-java-api-3.0.2-bin  from 
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/
for connecting to face book.I want to use this api in my java application to connect Facebook.I am developing a desktop application for this purpose.I have created account on Face book and registered as a developer.

Is it possible to connect Facebook from my java application?

If yes please, can some one send me the example code for that and treat me as a New Bee in this facebook integration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried out the various examples available in the api wiki?

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

Google also returns various tutorial pages:

http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/01/facebook-java-apieng.html

http://www.socialjava.com/socialjavastepbystep.html

You should try working through some of these and posting specific questions about problems you run into.

Comment: http://www.socialjava.com/socialjavastepbystep.html link broken and outdated

Answer (score 10):

Note that the facebook-java-api project is now dead.

Use instead: 
http://restfb.com/

Comment: The other project is dead this is the better answer.

Comment: This is the right answer in current context. Other project seems dead