# Demo example for how to get data of your facebook account in to your java class?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, user-interface

Can anybody have demo code to get user data (like Username,last name) from his facebook account in to the java code? I have gone thru the sample API but it will help me to reduce my work if I can use some reusable code.

Thank you
hp

Comment: TO be more specific, when user Logsin , He should get the username, his basic info like name, lastname and his likes.Thank you

Comment: Facebook API is homework now? I remember professors doing everything they could to keep kids off facebook in lecture. "The times, they are a changin'"

Comment: Hmmm, if I remember correctly "reusable code" in school when I was in school was synonymous with "cheating."  Are you sure the point of the assignment wasn't to write said code?

Comment: No sir :), its not assignment :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Facebook JAVA API in my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022336/how-can-i-use-facebook-java-api-in-my-application)

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022336/how-can-i-use-facebook-java-api-in-my-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the facebook-java-api project is now dead.

Use instead: 
http://restfb.com/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Java API Google Group:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

Examples of the FB Java API (including what you're looking for):
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

---

One suggestion I have would be to use Google Web Toolkit and/or the Apache HTTP Client.

**GWT:** http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ Let's you write complex web-app code in Java, and automatically ports it to Javascript for you. No servlets required.

**Apache HTTP Client:** http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ Provides helper methods for things such as AJAX calls, sending/receiving data, passing cookies/parameters with requests, etc.

Just have a look at Facebook's API, and mess around with either of these tools.  Also, have a look at these official Facebook resources:

**Facebook API Sandbox:** https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

**Facebook Developer App:** https://www.facebook.com/developers/

**Sample Apps:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/