# Including facebook.php in tomcat + liferay

Tags: facebook, tomcat6, liferay

I want to make a site for me in which I can use the facebook api features. 
I got a tomcat webserver ans liferay is installed on it.

Now I need to implement the facebook.php to this but I don't know where to put it. 
I wrote some code in php to get for example my id or to post into my own profile. But liferay oder tomcat couldn't load the things from facebook.php so the server doesn't know the methods and can't do what I want him to do.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually done it before because I've tried to keep PHP code off Liferay and used other methods to access 3rd APIs. However the Tomcat wiki has a post on it:

[Installing PHP on Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp)

Or what maybe a better option is you use the [Facebook JavaScript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and you create a new Liferay portlet which uses this API instead of using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I use Facebook JAVA API in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022336) will help you find the java api for facebook. With regards to getting started with programming: That one is far beyond what can be answered here. But basically: Try to access the API in the language that you're working in. Don't bridge to a different language in order to bridge then to an external system.

There are a lot more hits when you google for *facebook java api* in case that link doesn't help.