# Does facebook exposes its APIs through webservices?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to make a facebook application in java using servlets and JSP.But as i found out facebook does not provide any SDK for java.And i do not wish to  use the third party APIs like restfb etc.Does facebook exposes its APIs through webservices which i can use using java?
Also can GRAPH API be regarded as a webservice?

Comment: I don't think you did much research. Graph API appears to be, for all intents and purposes, a web service. Did you even look at it? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has exposed it services through RESTfull webservices.
Have a look at facebook graph api and FQL.

Yes you are correct in saying facebook doesnot have a JAVA SDK. But you can always use third party libraries. Using a library is not a compulsion as you can make the calls directly.

Good Luck.

Comment: Well in my project i am not allowed to use third party libraries?Is there any other way out?

Comment: Like I said make the Rest calls directly using HttpURLConnection in Java

Comment: Is it possible to make a facebook app by just using the GRAPH API and not using any SDK?

Comment: @user1411619 Again, did you even look at the Graph API page? It's a web service. Also, it's Graph API, not GRAPH API. Graph is not an acronym.

Comment: Afcorse its possible. Libraries make life easier though. But you can always make facebook app without any third party library.

Comment: Thanks subirkumarsao.Would you suggest that PHP would be a much better option than java for facebook app development?

Comment: Php is going to help u devlop fast. But there is nothing u cannot do in java.

Answer (score 0):

While Facebook does not provide an *official* API, there are some ways you can connect to FB from Java. For example, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2022336/209629).