# Can I do oauth2 authentication for Facebook by java service calls? I don't want to use any kind of UI

Tags: java, web-services, oauth-2.0

Please help me. I am trying to implement validation by Facebook login, without using UI.

Comment: Hello prabhudayal acharya. Have you tried to code anything yet? Have you tried to look at the Facebook API? If you have some work to show us, please do, so that we can help you solve your problem more efficiently.

Comment: Of course, you can use the facebook api to connect with facebook open authentication, and you their rederict uri for UI,

Please check this link out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022336/how-can-i-use-facebook-java-api-in-my-application, there are some options you could be interest in.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I am a beginner to oauth2 process. Initially I thought I can hit a facebook API with username and password as post request and authenticate a user. And I came to know that I was wrong. Correct me if I am wrong. There is no way any authenticator will allow user id and password in plain text.